# Starting game timer after initial interaction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I've created an idle warning to notify users that the game will restart shortly due to inactivity but I'm still having one problem - as soon as the game restarts the timer fires instead of firing only after the first time a user begins interacting (first touches the screen). What am I missing in my code?

```
private Vector3 prevMousePosition = Vector3.zero;
public GameObject timeOutWarning;

void Start()
{       
    prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.anyKeyDown || Input.mousePosition != prevMousePosition)
    {
        StartGameTimer();
        timeOutWarning.SetActive(false);
    }
    prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
}

void StartGameTimer()
{
    CancelInvoke ();
    Invoke ("ShowRestartWarning", 10);
}

void ShowRestartWarning()
{
    timeOutWarning.SetActive(true);

    Debug.Log ("Restart Warning Popup");

    CancelInvoke ();
    Invoke ("RestartGame", 10);
}

void RestartGame()
{
    Debug.Log("Restarting Game Now");

    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears most likely to be your first line of code:

```
if(Input.anyKeyDown || Input.mousePosition != prevMousePosition)
```

The first time you hit this line, `prevMousePosition` will be `0,0` (unless you're initializing it elsewhere). Your mouse position is unlikely to be that, so you'll trigger the timer straight away.

The most obvious solution for this will be to set a useful value before `Update` is first called:

```
void Start()
{
    previousMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
}
```